# What is the wp_postmeta table

Tags: wordpress, schema, meta, posts

From my understanding, the wp_postmeta extends the schema for wp_post.  So basically the standard fields/structure for a post will be found in wp_posts, and if any post(s) needed their own set of fields/attributes etc, they would be defined in wp_postmeta table.  So I wanted to know if I'm right about this or not?

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are absolutely right.
If there exist some meta box or "own set of fields/attributes" wp_postmeta table will store those field's values.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/2a/WP3.9.4-ERD.png

wp_postmeta (similar to wp_usermeta for users and wp_commentmenta for comments) stores any additional information which is connected to a post somehow especially user-defined.

Use the functions

```
add_post_meta()
update_post_meta()
get_post_meta()
```

which are already implementing object and array serialization/deserialization (and a lot of more) in order to store custom information which is not stored within the wp_posts table.

Comment: If i wanted to have a look at something i would've done so beforehand and noted it in my question.  This is a Q&A website, please follow the rules at the bare minimum.  Ty nonetheless.